# Learning to program with Facebook or Foursquare APIs?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, foursquare

I would like to know if there are online video resources to help people learn how to program using Facebook or Foursquare APIs?

Comment: I've seen a few - any particular sdk? http://developers.facebook.com is definitely in my bookmarks...

Comment: Facebook API with javascript SDK would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no video resources for the foursquare API, but there is a straightforward tutorial available @ https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/samples as well as plenty of documentation on our developer site: https://developer.foursquare.com/